# How would I change this regular expression to accept a single decimal of .5 at the end?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
/^(([0-2][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9])|360)$/
```

This accepts numbers from 000-360. I also want it to accept the decimal .5 at the end. No other decimal should be accepted and it should also accept no decimal at all. Also 360.5 should not be accepted. How would I do this?

Comment: `000<=x<=360.5` in .5 increments? Just want to be clear of the question...

Comment: Sorry, 360.5 should not be accepted, I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `000 <= x <= 360`, but allowing for `.5` values within that range:

```
^((?:[0-2][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9])(?:\.5)?|360)$
```

I've added a non-capturing group to target `000`-`359` and added an optional `.5` group after that.

```
^                                # Start of string
 (                               # Begin capture
  (?:[0-2][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9])    # 000-359
  (?:\.5)?                         # (optional) .5 suffix
  |                              # -- OR --
  360                              # 360 (explicitly)
 )                               # End capture
$                                # End of string
```

This will also make the first capture group record whatever the number is.

Comment: Thank you for such a in-depth answer! Much appreciated. What would I change if I wanted to accept .0 as well?

Answer (score 3):

```
/^(([0-2][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9])|360)(|\.5)$/
```

Comment: Exclusive of `360.5` (Your pattern also messes up capture group (if the OP cares about that.))

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^((([0-2][0-9]{2}|3[0-5][0-9])(\.5)?)|360)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/gQ1vO6/2

Comment: Probably want `?` quantified and not `*` (0 or 1 time).

Comment: This actually only works with half-values within `300 <= x < 359`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `(\.5)*` at the end right before your line ending.